# mstsc RDP Freezing after entering login credentials

Tags: rdp, mstsc

Just received brand new Windows 8.1 PRO DELL laptop.  Everything fully updated and running MSTSC version 6.3.9600.17415.  I am able to RDP into server 2003 servers, but so far unable to connect to server 2008 standard or R2.  A few details:

** When a successful connection is made on a server 2003, I click on mstsc > select my server > click connect > I receive a message with a yellow banner "The identity of the remote computer cannot be verified.  Do you want to connect anyway?"  And it always connects....     ON 2008 (or other unsuccessful machines) I click mstsc > enter server name > the verification message does NOT show up.  I just go straight to the login screen.

** Enter username/password > click ok > login screen goes away > Connection screen remains but is completely frozen.

** Other Windows 8.1 machines on my same network with the same RDP version can connect just fine to 2008 servers.

** Even if I cancel out of the login window, the connection window will be frozen.

What I have tried:
-Disabling Kapersky and Windows firewall
-Changed display resolution to small.
-Turned off ALL local resources (Smart card reader, clipboard, drives, disabled audio, etc).
-Disabled smart card reader in device manager.
-Tried running as administrator

Thanks!

Comment: Try disabling BitMap Caching in your RDP client (on the EXPERIENCE tab).

Comment: Reboot the 2008 server?